# What are the alternatives to returning a discriminated union from a function?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

I'm experimenting with rewriting a complicated piece of code using F#. 
For this particular code base, discriminated unions help me a lot, so I'm focusing on using them as much as possible. Specifically, exhaustiveness checks on DUs is helping me avoid lots and lots of bugs.

However, I'm facing a repeating pattern of having to use `match ... with` to the extent that the clutter in the code is offsetting the benefit I'm getting from exhaustiveness check.
I simplified the pattern I'm dealing with as much as I can and tried to come up with an example that demonstrates the structure of the code I'm writing. The real code base is a lot more complicated and it is in a completely different domain but at the language level, this example represents the issue.

Let's say we want to get some about shoppers based on a classification of shoppers: they're either cat people or dog people. The key thing here is classifying some types (tuples) via DUs. 
Here are the domain types:

```
type PetPerson =
    |CatPerson
    |DogPerson

type CatFood =
    |Chicken
    |Fish

type DogFood =
    |Burger
    |Steak

//some cat food, shopper's age and address
type CatFoodShopper = CatFoodShopper of (CatFood list * int * string)    

//some dog food, shopper's age and number of children
type DogFoodShopper = DogFoodShopper of (DogFood list * int * int)
```

Leaving aside the horrible way we're feeding the poor animals, this domain model needs a function to map `PetPerson` to `CatFoodShopper` or `DogFoodShopper`
At this point, my initial thought is to define a Shopper type, since I cannot return two different types from the following function, based on the results of pattern matching:

```
type Shopper =
    |CatFShopper of CatFoodShopper
    |DogFShopper of DogFoodShopper

let ShopperViaPersonality = function
    |CatPerson -> CatFShopper (CatFoodShopper ([Chicken;Fish], 32, "Hope St"))
    |DogPerson -> DogFShopper (DogFoodShopper ([Burger;Steak], 45, 1))
```

This solves the problem but then I have lots of places in the code (really a lot) where I end up with a `PetPerson` and need to get a `CatFoodShopper` or a `DogFoodShopper` based on what the `PetPerson` value is. This leads to unnecessary pattern matching for cases I know I don't have at hand. Here is an example:

```
let UsePersonality (x:int) (y:PetPerson) =
    //x is used in some way etc. etc.
    match y with
    |CatPerson as c -> //how can I void the following match?
        match (ShopperViaPersonality c) with
        |CatFShopper (CatFoodShopper (lst,_,_))-> "use lst and return some string "
        | _ -> failwith "should not have anything but CatFShopper"
    |DogPerson as d -> //same as before. I know I'll get back DogFShopper
        match (ShopperViaPersonality d) with
        |DogFShopper (DogFoodShopper (lst, _,_)) -> "use lst and return other string"
        |_ -> failwith "should not have anything but DogFShopper"
```

As you can see, I have to write pattern matching code even when I know I'll be getting back a particular value. I have no way of concisely associating the `CatPerson` value to `CatFoodShopper` value.

In order to improve things at the call site, I considered using F#'s way of mimicking type classes via interfaces, based on lots of example available here:

```
type IShopperViaPersonality<'T> =
    abstract member ShopperOf: PetPerson -> 'T

let mappingInstanceOf<'T> (inst:IShopperViaPersonality<'T>) p = inst.ShopperOf p

let CatPersonShopper =
    {new IShopperViaPersonality<_> with
        member this.ShopperOf x =
            match x with
            |CatPerson -> CatFoodShopper ([Chicken;Fish], 32, "Hope St")
            | _ -> failwith "This implementation is only for CatPerson"}
let CatPersonToShopper = mappingInstanceOf CatPersonShopper

let DogPersonShopper =
    {new IShopperViaPersonality<_> with
        member this.ShopperOf x =
            match x with
            |DogPerson -> DogFoodShopper ([Burger;Steak], 45, 1)
            | _ -> failwith "This implementation is only for DogPerson"}
let DogPersonToShopper = mappingInstanceOf DogPersonShopper
```

So I no longer have a `Shopper` type to represent both cat food shoppers and dog food shoppers, but instead an interface defines the mapping from `PetPerson` values to specific shopper types. I also have individual partially applied functions to make things even easier at the call site.

```
let UsePersonality1 (x:int) (y:PetPerson) =
    match y with
    |CatPerson as c ->
        let (CatFoodShopper (lst,_,_)) = CatPersonToShopper c
        "use lst and return string"
    |DogPerson as d ->
        let (DogFoodShopper (lst,_,_)) = DogPersonToShopper d
        "use lst and return string"
```

This approach works better when using PetPerson values, but I'm now left with the task of defining these individual functions to keep things clean at the call site.

Note that this example is meant to demonstrate the trade off between using a DU and using an interface to return different types based on the classifying DU parameter, if I may call it that. So don't hang up on my meaningless use of return values etc.

My question is: are there any other ways I can accomplish the semantics of classifying a bunch of tuple (or record) types? If you're thinking active patterns, they're not an option because in the real code base the DUs have more than seven cases, which is the limit for active patterns, in case they would be of help. So do I have any other options to improve on the above approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious way to go about this is to call `ShopperViaPersonality` *before* matching `PetPerson`, not after:

```
let UsePersonality (x:int) (y:PetPerson) =
    //x is used in some way etc. etc.
    match ShopperViaPersonality y with
    | CatFShopper (CatFoodShopper (lst,_,_))-> "use lst and return some string "
    | DogFShopper (DogFoodShopper (lst, _,_)) -> "use lst and return other string"
```

Also note that if the sole purpose of `ShooperViaPersonality` is to support pattern matches, you may be better off making it an active pattern:

```
let (|CatFShopper|DogFShopper|) = function
    | CatPerson -> CatFShopper ([Chicken;Fish], 32, "Hope St")
    | DogPerson -> DogFShopper ([Burger;Steak], 45, 1)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
let UsePersonality (x:int) (y:PetPerson) =
    //x is used in some way etc. etc.
    match y with
    | CatFShopper (lst,_,_) -> "use lst and return some string "
    | DogFShopper (lst, _,_) -> "use lst and return other string"
```

Logically, an active pattern is pretty much the same as a DU + a function, but on syntactic level, notice how much less nesting there is now.

Comment: Thanks Fyodor. You're right about calling the ShopperViaPersonality first, but unfortunately, that is not possible within the original code base. This is an oversimplified example focusing on the language level trade-off. Re active patterns, I'd use them if they were not limited to seven. I actually wrote this at the end of the question. The original code has  more than seven possible cases in the DUs. I would consider 'No, you don't have any other options than these' a valid answer to my question. I'm basically trying to identify what is possible with F# in this scenario.

Comment: Why is calling the function before the match not possible in the original codebase? Your example does not show this, and you're not mentioning it in the text.

Comment: I actually tried to mention it in the text but sorry if I failed to make it clear. Basically the whole point is to encode a compile time classification of tuples using DUs. The logic is driven by the classifying DU (exemplified by PetPerson) and context of the call is a lot more complicated. It is hard to strip the problem down to a simple example, but this is the setting I have in place :)

Comment: Well, if you don't describe the problem, then I'm afraid nobody will be able to provide a solution. Logically thinking, if there is a single way to get a discriminated tuple from its classification, then why not use it instead of the classification itself. And if the ways of obtaining different tuples are distinct and require different context, then surely they ought to be modeled via different functions instead of a single `ShopperViaPersonality`? If you take care to actually describe your problem, I'm sure the community will come up with a solution. My answer addresses your problem as descri

Comment: ...as described in the original post.

Comment: I did not say your answer does not address my problem. It does. Especially using active patterns improves upon what I'm doing but it won't help due to its upper limit of seven. So once again: thanks. As I indicated: this is about exploring options I have in this specific case, so every suggestion counts and helps. I'd be surprised if another answer improves upon yours, I'll probably accept it after a short wait.

Comment: I'm not arguing for accepting my answer. I don't care very much. I'm trying to help. What I'm saying is, if you describe why exactly it's not possible to call the function before the match, I (or somebody else) may be able to provide a better answer.